# Rioxarray dimension missing coordinates

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm currently using the Python module rioxarray to clip an Xarray dataset based on a specific geometry to produce a latitude/longitude grid of coordinates. My data is below:

```
obs_dataset_full

xarray.Dataset

Dimensions:
Lat: 451 Lon: 350 lat: 450 lon: 350

Coordinates:
Lon
(Lon)
int64
0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 345 346 347 348 349
Lat
(Lat)
int64
0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 446 447 448 449 450
Longitude
(lon)
float64
-105.7 -105.7 ... -78.34 -78.26
Latitude
(lat)
float64
35.04 35.08 35.11 ... 51.52 51.56
spatial_ref
()
int64
0
Data variables:
precip_var
(lon, lat, Lon, Lat)
float64
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 nan

Attributes:
grid_mapping :
spatial_ref
```

Note: The Lon/Lat dimensions are irrelevant; I'm trying to utilize the lon/lat, which have the actual coordinates.

```
obs_dataset_full.rio.write_crs('EPSG:4326',inplace = True)
obs_dataset_cropped = obs_dataset_full.rio.clip(geometries=cropping_geometries, crs='EPSG:4326')
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
DimensionMissingCoordinateError: lon missing coordinates.
```

Both the obs_dataset_full dataset and the precip_var data array have the appropriate coordinates, and the rioxarray documentation page is not particularly clear as to what this exception entails. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Try to define spatial dimension names before calling `clip`:
`obs_dataset_full.rio.set_spatial_dims('Lon', 'Lat', inplace=True)` ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are facing is that `rioxarray` expects your spatial dimensions and coordinate to have the same name. I would recommend using the `rename` methods of in xarray to rename the dimensions and coordinates so they are both `longitide` and `latitude` or `x` and `y`.

Comment: Worked for me, great tip!